# Slick slider blinks at the end of the rotation for reapeating

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

I faced an issue with slick slider https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/, I used slick slider to create this slider , this slider has 6 slide. The problem is that when you want to move from slide 6 to slide 1 it has a blink, and again for moving from slide 6 to slide one it has another blink.

I want to fix this blink. See this video to watch how it works and what I mean exactly.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZZlO.jpg

this is the library that I used

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/plugins.js"></script>
```

This is the html

```
 <div id="screenshot-area" class="screenshot-area bg-white section-padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Section Title -->
            <div class="section-title text-center col-xs-12">
                <h4 >SCREENSHOT</h4>
                <span class="borderbottomblue"></span>
                <p>
                    
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Screen Shot Slider -->
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="screenshot-slider">
                    <div class="single-screen"><img src="Content/img/screenshot/Meinu_screen_1.png" alt="Mein_Übersetzer iPhone screenshot" /></div>
                    <div class="single-screen"><img src="Content/img/screenshot/Meinu_screen_2.png" alt="Mein_Übersetzer iPhone screenshot" /></div>
                    <div class="single-screen"><img src="Content/img/screenshot/Meinu_screen_3.png" alt="Mein_Übersetzer iPhone screenshot" /></div>
                    <div class="single-screen"><img src="Content/img/screenshot/Meinu_screen_4.png" alt="Mein_Übersetzer iPhone screenshot" /></div>
                    <div class="single-screen"><img src="Content/img/screenshot/Meinu_screen_5.png" alt="Mein_Übersetzer iPhone screenshot" /></div>
                     <div class="single-screen"><img src="Content/img/screenshot/Meinu_screen_1.png" alt="Mein_Übersetzer iPhone screenshot" /></div>
                        
                         
                         
                        
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    

$('.screenshot-slider').slick({

    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    focusOnSelect: true,
    centerPadding: '228px',
    responsive: [
      {
          breakpoint: 1250,
          settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerPadding: '230px',
          }
      },
      
       {
          breakpoint: 1200,
          settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerPadding: '175px',
             
          }
      },
      
      
      {
          breakpoint: 992,
          settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerPadding: '0px',
              slidesToShow: 3,
          }
      },
      //{
      //  breakpoint: 769,
      //  settings: {
      //    arrows: false,
      //    centerPadding: '0px',
      //  }
      //},
      {
          breakpoint: 769,
          settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerPadding: '0px',
              dots: true,
              slidesToShow: 3,
          }
      },
         {
             breakpoint: 768,
             settings: {
                 arrows: false,
                 centerPadding: '0px',
                 dots: true,
                 slidesToShow: 2,
             }
         },
      {
          breakpoint: 480,
          settings: {
              arrows: false,
              centerPadding: '0px',
              dots: true,
              slidesToShow: 1,
          }
      },
    ]
});

</script>
```

I think it relates to the way it chooses the active and current slides , seems the calculation needs more time for this.

### Update

I found this bunch of CSS might cause this problem because as I remove this bunch of code, the current slide won't be bigger while active but the blink won't happen.

```
.screenshot-area{}
.screenshot-slider {}
.screenshot-slider .slick-list {
  padding-bottom: 60px !important;
  padding-top: 60px !important;
}
.single-screen {
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
.single-screen.slick-active {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
          transform: scale(1.15);
  z-index: 2;
}
.single-screen.slick-center {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
          transform: scale(1.3);
  z-index: 3;
}
.single-screen img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: you must have applied particular styles to `.single-screen`: I can see from your video, slides preceding and succeeding the current one are customized (they are bigger than the others). That must be affecting your slider.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All the slides works properly the way I want but the blink is just for the last one when wants to go to first one. at the end of rotation. the centre one should be bigger than others because I used center mode. I really appreciate if you can help me to just fix the blink problem. I really need a help on this @GrafiCode

Comment: @GrafiCode Would you kindly please take a look at the update? I think I found what bunch of Css code is causing this problem?

Comment: what if you comment out all the `scale` styles in your CSS? does that make the slider behave correctly?

Comment: @GrafiCode thank you for your care. If I remove the scale lines, the blink will be fixed but the performance won't be the same as the video, The current one won't be bigger or focused . Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue
1- change the version of slick:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.min.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
```

2- update the style

```
.slick-slide {
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            }
            .slick-slide.slick-center {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.3);
                -ms-transform: scale(1.3);
                    transform: scale(1.3);
                    z-index: 3;
            position: relative;

            }

            .screenshot-slider {
            margin: 0 auto;
            position: relative;
            } 

            .single-screen {
            padding: 0;
            z-index: 1;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
            }
            .single-screen img {
            width: 100%;
            }
```

3- add this script after `$('.screenshot-slider').slick();`

```
 $('.slick-slide').click(function(e){
            e.currentTarget.classList.add('slick-current', 'slick-active','slick-center');
        });
```